# Checking for unique maps in csv file using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I am attaching a screen shot of an excel file. It contains x,y and z values in three columns. What i want to check is how many functional loops are present, meaning "(x>x),(x>y, y>x), (x>y,x>y1), (x>y,y>x1)". I want to write a sample code to check the number of functional loops present in this excel file. I wrote a sample code to check for (x>x), but i am not able to write a code for the other loops. Any help will be appreciated.

what it means by x>x is both elements in column 1 and 2 are equal

What it means by (x>y, y>x) is element in column 1 maps to an element in column 2 and the same element in column 2 maps to the same element in column 1

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/amit/Desktop/playing_with_pandas.csv')
xy_data = df.iloc[:,0:2]
x>x = xy_data[xy_data.nunique(1).eq(1)]
print("the number of x>x are",x>x)
```

[Screen shot of csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYn5I.png)

Comment: What does "(x>y,x>y1)"?

Comment: It means the same x value have different y values. For eg: if you look at the screen shot, then you can see for the value x=1, it has three different y values, 2, 9, 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*x>x* is

```
(df.x == df.y).sum()
```

*x>y, y>x* is

```
df.duplicated().sum()
```

*x>y, x>y1* is

```
(df.y.groupby(df.x).nunique() > 1).sum()
```

*x>y, x1>y* is

```
(df.x.groupby(df.y).nunique() > 1).sum()
```

Comment: What If i want to calculate the mean and standard deviation in each case of this. I tried by using df.mean(). It doesnot work